# Template Fragment does not generate output if script is called twice

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using the enhanced reporting feature from Sparx EA (version 10.0.1007) to generate several tables from User Interface design with Fragment Template and JScript.

My idea is to add TaggedValues for specific EA Element, such as

1. Edit and RichEdit will have Minimum, Maximum, Input Type, Default Value
2. Buttons will have IsDefault, Action
3. ... etc

and then create a table for each of them in the RTF report. The output will look like:

```
No  Name      Mandatory  Input Type    Min  Max  Notes 
1   Textbox1     Y       alphanumeric   1   255  This is note for Textbox1
2   Textbox2     N       numeric        0   255  This is note for Textbox2

No  Name      Action            IsDefault   Notes 
1   Button1   Clear all input      N        This is note for Button1
2   Button2   Submit the data      Y        This is note for Button2
```

I've been able to create the fragment and JScript to create a table. Since the scripts to generate those tables are alike, I created a single script which is called by each fragment script to avoid boilerplate code.

Here is the configuration:

```
Main template - include Fragment 2 and Fragment 3
Fragment 2 - calls JScript GenerateTableInput(#PACKAGEID#)
Fragment 3 - calls JScript GenerateTableButton(#PACKAGEID#)
JScript GenerateTableInput - calls GenerateTable(packageID, 1)
JScript GenerateTableButton- calls GenerateTable(packageID, 2)
```

When I use above configuration, only Fragment 2 or Fragment 3 is included in the generated document. However, if I created two partial scripts (boilerplate code), both Fragment 2 and Fragment 3 are generated.

Do I miss any configuration, or is this a bug in Sparx EA?

Comment: Hiya! Any Update on it? Got the same problem here

Answer (score 3):

David
It seems to work ok for me, I have a script with two functions (MyRtfData, MyRtfData2), having two template fragments to call these methods (DocProperties, DocProperties2) and have used these two in a template, and the generated document has fragment 1 and fragment 2 rendered.

[image: Doc Fragment Example]

Comment: Does both MyRtfData and MyRtfData calls another script?

Comment: Yeah, both calls, the same "DocProperties" Script, refer to the images for both template fragment definitions.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But the entry points for both are different, does each of them call the same function in it?

Comment: Tried that.. Works OK for me  
 function MyRtfData(objectID)
 {
 return doRTF(objectID);
 };
 
 function MyRtfData2(objectID)
 {
 return doRTF(objectID);
 }; 
 
function doRTF(objectID)
{

Comment: What is the EA version that you used?

Comment: I tried v11.0.1106 and it is working. I voted your answer and put mine also. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Edit: still not working. I may need to push my code in the question